# Are server scripts backed up by mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I restored a backup created by mongodump using mongorestore. I was trying to see the server scripts those were expected to be there, but could not find them.

```
mongos> db.loadServerScripts()
mongos> db.system.js.distinct("_id")
[]
```

So was wondering, whether the server scripts really make to the dump file in mongodb.

Can  someone tell me the behavior of dump and restore in terms of server scripts?? Any links where this is documented??

Comment: just to check here - you took the dump of entire database ? may be you took few collections only.

Comment: Not sure .. but I am assuming the dump to be of entire db. Can you please tell me the behavior of dump and restore in terms of server scripts?? Any links where it is documented.